# FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation Failed - process out of memory

Tags: json, node.js, jsonlint

I'm trying to run `jsonlint` on a 40MB JSON file, but it halts execution with an exit status of `5`, and the following error message:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation Failed - process out of memory
```

Does anyone know how I can get this JSON pretty-printed? I wonder if it has to do with node's `--max-old-space-size` argument, but I'm also unsure how to pass this to the installed executable file.

If there's another approach I could take to rendering this with human-readable indentation, I'd appreciate those suggestions, too.

Comment: Are you trying to pretty-print the JSON or validate it? jsonlint is a validator. To pretty-print you can do `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(...), false, 2)`.

Comment: Definitely pretty-print, but it still hits the same error, even with `node --max-old-space-size=2000 prettyPrint.js`. My entire script is: `var fs = require('fs'); var f = fs.readFileSync('ugly.json'), o = JSON.parse(f), p = JSON.stringify( o, null, 3 ); fs.writeFileSync(p, 'pretty.json');`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought about how big this JSON is going to be pretty-printed? Is the 40MB mostly single long strings or is this a ton of nested objects? I ask because it isn't necessarily impossible that it would be bigger than 2000MB when you factor in that you'll also be taking up a lot of RAM to store the parsed structure.

Comment: It's lots and lots of nested objects. I managed to successfully stringify it using an indentation of `'\t'`, and it came out to about 72MB. The linecount is 1429654. If I could just change that to space indentation instead of tab, that would be fine, too, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

jsonlint is based on Jison, that's a parser generator. It's simple to write, but it's extremely slow. So just don't use that unless you really need some of it's features (like sorting object keys).

If you want to pretty-print JSON, either use built-in - `JSON.stringify(object, '\t')`, or [jju](https://github.com/rlidwka/jju) module - `require('jju').stringify(object, {mode: 'json'})` for more compact, but still human-readable representation.

40MB will result to about 200-300MB of space, which is definitely not that big.